# Limit ${\lim_{x\to 0^+}}\frac{(e^{4 x}-1)^{13}(1-\cos \left( 3 x \right))^{12}(1-\cos \left( x \right))^{7}}{(e^{2x}-1)^{4}(e^{8 x}-1)^{47}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$${\lim_{x\to 0^+}}\frac{(e^{4 x}-1)^{13}(1-\cos \left( 3 x \right))^{12}(1-\cos \left( x \right))^{7}}{(e^{2x}-1)^{4}(e^{8 x}-1)^{47}}$$

I thought to use $1-cos(x)=2sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$ and to take out common factor, but it did not help

Any suggestions where to start?

Comment: Using a simple taylor series you get e^ax-1 = ax and 1-cosbx= b^2/2. Putting these in the limit, the numerator is  Cx^51 and the denominator is Cx^51 so the answer will be a finite nonzero number. Plugging it in the limit is approximately 4^13*3^24/2^12*1/2^7 /(2^4*8^47)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$  and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$

So we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\alpha x}-1}{\alpha x}=1\Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\alpha x}-1}{x}=\alpha$  and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos (\beta x)}{(\beta x)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos (\beta x)}{x^2}=\frac{\beta^2}{2}$

Comment: So I need to multiply and divide by the $\alpha x$ and $x^2$ each one to the corresponding power?

Comment: Yes. Our u can put $e^{\alpha x}-1=\alpha x$ and $\displaystyle 1-\cos(\beta x)=\frac{\beta^2 x^2}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Your limit is:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{e^{4x}-1}{4x}\right)^{13}\cdot\frac{\left(1-\cos\left(3x\right)\right)^{12}}{\left(3x\right)^{24}}\cdot$$$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(1-\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{7}}{x^{14}}\cdot\left(\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}\right)^{4}\cdot\left(\frac{8x}{e^{8x}-1}\right)^{47}\cdot\frac{\left(4x\right)^{13}\left(3x\right)^{24}x^{14}}{\left(2x\right)^{4}\left(8x\right)^{47}}$$$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{e^{4x}-1}{4x}\right)^{13}\cdot\left(\frac{\color{red}{\sin^{2}\left(3x\right)}}{\left(1+\cos\left(3x\right)\right)\color{red}{\left(3x\right)^{2}}}\right)^{12}$$$$\cdot\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\color{red}{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)}}{\left(1+\cos\left(x\right)\right)\color{red}{x^{2}}}\right)^{7}\cdot\left(\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}\right)^{4}\cdot\left(\frac{8x}{e^{8x}-1}\right)^{47}\cdot\frac{\left(4x\right)^{13}\left(3x\right)^{24}x^{14}}{\left(2x\right)^{4}\left(8x\right)^{47}}$$$$=1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{12}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{7}\cdot1\cdot1\cdot\frac{2^{26}\cdot3^{24}}{2^{4}\cdot2^{141}}\cdot\frac{x^{51}}{x^{51}}$$$$=\color{red}{8.1053301914×10^{−31}}$$

Where I use some basic limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{ax}-1}{ax}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)}{ax}=1$$

Where $a$ is a real numbers.